# Is '게' exactly the same as '것이'? Is there a wider pattern or is this a specific case?

Tags: grammar, contraction

I've read that '게' is equivalent to '것이'.

Is that 100% true? are the following pairs of sentences the same?

> 그것이 진짜 예뻐요 
> 그게 진짜 예뻐요
>
> 그것이 너무 무거워 
> 그게 너무 무거워

I'm also wondering if 것이 → 게 is a case of any wider pattern, or if it's a very specific contraction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, they are identical in meaning.  It is a contraction, like "don't" in English.  In formal writing, contractions are used less often, also like in English.  You probably wouldn't see "don't" in a legal document, right?  It's the same story.

Similar are: 이것이 >> 이게 and 저것이 >> 저게

Also, with the topic/contrast marker: (이/그/저)것은 >> (이/그/저)건
And with the direct object marker: (이/그/저)것을 >> (이/그/저)걸

A quick google search of, for instance, "는 게 어떻습니까" will show you 15,000 examples of this contraction used in formal cases.  There is no rule against it, per se.

In fact, 거 is just another spelling of 것 that is used in certain circumstances.

Yet another contraction with 것 is in the probable future form, 것이다 and it's permutations, where the ㅅ and the 이 contract out, giving 거다, 겁니다, 거지, etc.

There are more.

One thing to point out is that 게 is used other ways, for example to make adverbs and passive forms from verb roots, so be careful to pay attention...in fact i found this a bit confusing when first learning the language.

Comment: welcome to the site! I've combined your two answers - hope that's ok.

Answer (score 4):

Language is always changing. The object 것 *(thing)* and subject particle 이 *(marking the subject of the clause)* as you state, are being contracted.  But the standard language *(표준 언어)* is 것이. While 게 (when used as the contracted form of 것이 is not standard language but a form of the standard adopted by generations that "made it their own".

I am also familiar with the ㅅ being dropped. As an example:

그건?? 아니야 그건 안돼!  *(That (near you)?? No way, that (near you) won't do!)*

**edit**

Also consider that these two "match" well with the level of respect to the hearer in their conjugations:

> 그게 좋아
> 그것이 좋습니다

as for the "middle" level, it could go either way

> 그게 좋아요
>
> 그것이 좋아요

Comment: So is it something used only by younger people in informal situations?

Comment: I have added an edit which seeks to further address the situational usage of the two.

Comment: 게 is informal, but it's still part of the standard language.  For example, see: http://krdic.naver.com/rescript_detail.nhn?seq=6593