# Is there a big difference between 하는 것이 좋다 and 하면 좋다?

Tags: grammar

> 그 책을 읽는 것이 좋다 
>   그 책을 읽으면 좋다

What's the difference between the 'feel' of these? I've read that 는 것이 좋다 has more of a feel of an instruction - "you should read this book". Is that correct? intuitively I would have thought it would be the other way around.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The phrase 면/으면 (one for verbs that don't end in a consonant/one for verbs that do) translates most directly to "if".

> 그 책을 읽는 것이 좋다

*Reading that book (near you) is good.*

> 그 책을 읽으면 좋다

*If you read that book (near you) it is good.*

Comment: Thanks for the answer - it's not so much the direct / literal translation that I'm interested in, but the different situations in which you might use each (if indeed they would be used differently).

Comment: Perhaps you would use "if" in a case where you were not certain the reader would read the book.  As you mention in your [other question](http://korean.stackexchange.com/questions/2162/is-%ea%b2%8c-exactly-the-same-as-%ea%b2%83%ec%9d%b4-is-there-a-wider-pattern-or-is-this-a-specific/2165?noredirect=1#comment1896_2165) one would probably not use **것이** since it is too "standard", but then, the **을** would likely be dropped too - 그책은 좋아 - 읽어봐!